# Set an expiration on a shared document

Tags: google-drive

I want to share a document with several people, but I want to rescind the document at the end of the month.

Is there a way I can do that automatically from within Google Drive?

Or am I consigned to putting a reminder in my calendar and doing it manually (and possibly forgetting or not having network access) when the day comes?

Comment: Phooey! [This is a new feature just introduced for Google Apps accounts](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/set-expiration-dates-for-access-to.html).

Answer (score 6):

While an expiration feature is being [introduced for Apps Domains](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2016/03/set-expiration-dates-for-access-to.html), for consumer accounts this process requires a script.

The steps are as follows:

1. Create a new Apps Script in Drive
2. Enter the code given below
3. Replace `ENTER_URL_HERE` with a URL of the file (either the one you get from right-click and "get link", or the one in your browser if you have the file open)
4. Set a trigger to run makePrivate on a specific date and time:

> [image: trigger]

```
function makePrivate() {
  var fileURL = 'ENTER_URL_HERE';

  var fileId = fileURL.match(/[\w-]{25,}/)[0];
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var users = file.getViewers().concat(file.getEditors());
  users.forEach(function (user) {file.revokePermissions(user);});
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);  
}
```

The script revokes any previously granted permissions to edit or view the file, either to individual people or to "anyone with a link".

---

Credit to [Henrique Abreu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840612) for the Id-extraction method.

Comment: Google consumer accounts requires a script. Google Apps for Work and similar accounts eventually will not require as Google is gradually launching a built-in feature to set sharing expiration date. See http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/set-expiration-dates-for-access-to.html